# Sharing a transform stream between multiple files?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm playing around with a Transform Streams but when ever I try to attach the stream to multiple file I get an error.

```
var T = new Transform;

T._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  T.push(encoding);
  done();

}

co( function *() {
  console.log('good');
  let files = yield fs.readdir(PATH);

  for ( let f = 0; f<files.length; f++ ) {
    console.log(files[f]);
    fs_old.createReadStream(PATH + '/' + files[f], {encoding: 'UTF-8'} ).pipe(Object.create(T)).pipe(fs_old.createWriteStream('out'));
  }
} )();
```

What I'm getting is,

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Transform.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:176:15)
    at Transform.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:664:33)
    at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:488:8)
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/test.js:37:72
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
    at next (/home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/co/index.js:70:21)
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/co/index.js:89:18
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/thunkify/index.js:28:12
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:97:15)
```

How I duplicate a Transform stream so I can run it on multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - it's not an error, it's a warning. Sometimes it's ok to see this, but not in this case. You need to have different transform streams. `Object.create` doesn't clone an object, it creates an object with a given prototype, so all functions and data are actually shared (same effect as just pass `T`). You need to use function like this instead:

```
function createTransform () {
  var T = new Transform;

  T._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
    T.push(encoding);
    done();
  }

  return T;
}
```

What you did was to create a single stream as is often done in abbreviated docs. This doesn't create a new stream for every file... The above will do that, but it goes about doing it by modifying the new Transform object. Alternatively you can subclass Transform,

```
function MyTransform (options) {
  // this is needed only so you can handle calls to MyTransform()
  // rather than `new MyTransform()`
  // (makes `this` in _transform point to stream)
  if (!(this instanceof MyTransform))
    return new MyTransform(options);

  Transform.call(this, options)
}

// make sure this comes before BEFORE you subclass the prototype
util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform);

MyTransform.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.push(chunk, encoding);
  done();
}
```

Comment: I'm going to edit this answer a lot @vkurchatkin, feel free to roll it back if you don't like the edits. It's a very good seed and I would not have accomplished it without you.

Comment: Does this remove leak warning? I still get the leak warning.